# Passing Variables to OpenApi Spec File for API Gateway Instantiation using CDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, openapi, aws-cdk

AWS CDK provides the ability to instantiate an API Gateway using an OpenAPI spec file that exists locally:

```
String specFilePath = "spec_file.yaml"

Asset openApiAsset = Asset.Builder.create(..., "assetId").path(specFilePath).build()

Map<String, String> transformMap = Map.of("Location", openAPIAsset.getS3ObjectUrl)

IResolvable data = Fn.transform("AWS::Include", transformMap)

InlineApiDefinition apiDefinition = ApiDefinition.fromInline(data)

SpecRestApi specRestApi = SpecRestApi.Builder.create(...).apiDefinition(apiDefinition)...
```

**How can variables be substituted into the spec file at runtime?**

In other words, is it possible for `spec_file.yaml` to have a placeholder resembling `${fill_in_at_runtime}` that can be passed in when instantiating the `ApiDefinition`?  Something of the form

```
InlineApiDefinition apiDefinition =
    ApiDefinition.fromInline(data).replace("fill_in_at_runtime", "42")
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.